# How to quickly make desired layouts in Java

Tags: java, layout, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I recently switched from .net to Eclipse plugin development.There are situations when my company ask me to create some complex layouts in SWT/JFace in Eclipse but i m not able to deliver it on time,since i m in a habbit of making layouts by dragging and droping controls by using Visual Studio IDE.Is there any IDE in java which provides such sort of drag drop facility to create layouts??If not then how can i make myself qucik in creating layouts in eclipse??Pls. suggest.

Comment: It is not clear that spending time looking for a fancy tool to do the job before you (and learning how to use it) is going to help you meet deadlines that you can't meet normally.  For a start, the tools may not be able to create complex layouts ... depending on the nature of the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It has an interesting way of controlling layout. The documentation is relatively good as well.

For an IDE [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) is an Eclipse plugin which is quite good. WindowBuilder Pro has support for MigLayout.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for the ease of drag and drop in eclipse, you must right click on your xml file and choose the "change layout" option. Select Absolute layout in the same and it works just like the drag and drop way! Hope this helps.